# VLC transmitter

Tags: led

I have constructed a 555 timer circuit as vlc(visible light communication) transmitter with ook modulation.which serial interface is best with PC to transfer a image.Am using MATLAB to send data serially.

Comment: Am a beginner to electronics

Comment: define data rate

Comment: PC's often have IRDA ports for IRDA 1 rates or IRDA2 but not so much recently

Comment: Nice story, now do you have a question?

Comment: @Andyaka, Sir my question is which serial interface will provide a reasonable baud rate and data rate to transfer an image through LED.?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mikroe.com/add-on-boards/communication/irda2/

This type is most commonly used over UART or RS232 ports

> "The TFDU4101 transceiver is an infrared transceiver module
>   compliant to the latest IrDA ® physical layer standard for fast
>   infrared data communication, supporting IrDA speeds up to
>   115.2 kbit/s (SIR)"

for faster serial baud rates if available, design can begin with these parts.
http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/sensors-transducers/irda-transceiver-modules/1966896?k=irda

Comment: thank u ...Am a very much new to electronics...baud rate and data rate depends on serial interface?

Comment: yes take number of pixels * bits per pixel (24) /baud rate  to get transit time  #[pix/image]*[bits/pix] / [bit/s] = [s/image]

Comment: thank you ..how to calculate data rate in visible light communication?.

Comment: first define bandwidth and distance required .  Mbps*distance squared is sort of constant due to path loss, options are many from 100kbps  to 1Mbps  for LED in short range like  1m  and lasers needed for longer range  Check out IRDA2  chips..  formula for number of pixels per second... like VGA 640x480x60hz x 24 bits=?  depends on what you need... for TV remote low Bw you get 30m range easy

Comment: 100 kbps to 1 Mbps  with one meter distance required.

Comment: thank u @Tony Stewart. Sir, Bandwidth depends on LED on-off time( frequency)? for example...if am driving LED at a frequency of 50KHz..so what will be my bandwidth and data rate?